# Trigger is not identifying the duplicate case with same subject and getting it closed by adding its case comment to the previous case

Tags: trigger, case

Can any one help me out with this scenario? Any help is very much appreciated.
We get cases created VIA Email. When there is a case created with the same subject line, it should be identified as a duplicate case and get closed by adding its case comment to the previous case.

Wrote a trigger which just creates a case, but it does not identifies the duplicate cases.

**Here is a code :**

```
trigger CaseTrigger123 on Case (after insert) {     
    Set<String> caseSubs = new Set<String>();       
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();       
    List<Case> listCases = new List<Case>();       
    List<CaseComment> listCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();        
    List<CaseComment> listInsertCaseComm = new List<CaseComment>();       
    Map<String, Id> mapCasSubId = new Map<String, Id>();        
    Map<Id, CaseComment> mapCaseIdCasComm = new Map<Id, CaseComment>();        
    Map<String,id> caseMap = new Map<String,id>();       
    Map<id,String> caseMap1 = new Map<id,String>();       
    Map<id,String> caseMap2 = new Map<id,String>();      
    Map<id,String> caseMap3 = new Map<id,String>();        
    Set<String> subjSet = new Set<String>();       
    List<CaseComment> updateLstCaseComment = new List<CaseComment>();       
    set<id> updateCasedIDs = new Set<Id>();        
    List<case> closeCasesCases = new List<case>();       
    set<String> subjCaseUpdated = new Set<String>();

    for(Case cas : trigger.new) {            
        //caseMap1.put(id)            
        caseIds.add(cas.id);           
        system.debug('Case ID++'+caseIds);       
    }

    if(!caseIds.IsEmpty()){          
        //for newly added case          
        for(case c : [SELECT  Id,Subject,Description,
            (SELECT Id, CommentBody,parentId from CaseComments) 
            from case where id IN:caseIds] ){               
            for(CaseComment c1 : c.CaseComments){                    
                caseMap.put(c.Subject,c1.CommentBody);                    
                caseMap2.put(c.Subject,c1.id);                    
                caseMap3.put(c.Subject,c1.parentId);                                                        
            }                        
        }

        for(String s : caseMap.Keyset()){               
            subjSet.add(s);            
        }           

        //for already existed cases in the data base           
        for(case ca : [SELECT  Id,Subject,Description,
            (SELECT Id, CommentBody,parentId from CaseComments) 
            from case where Subject IN:subjSet ]){                
                if(!caseIds.contains(ca.id)){                    
                    for(CaseComment cc : ca.CaseComments){                            
                        cc.CommentBody = cc.CommentBody + caseMap.get(ca.Subject);
                    }

                    for(case c:closeCasesCases){                   
                        c.status = 'Closed';                   
                        update c;               
                    }            
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Editor's note: Removed commented out code which may or may not be needed.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @nikkey. The first thing you should try do is formatting your code into something that is readable. Its nearly impossible for someone else to understand what the code is doing in its current format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling to read the code, but here's a possible solution that would do the dupe check:

```
trigger Case_AfterInsert (after insert)
{
  Map<String, List<Case>> subjectToCaseList = new Map<String, List<Case>>();
  Map<String, List<CaseComment> subjectToComments = new Map<String, List<CaseComment>>();


  List<Case> toUpdate = new List<Case>();
  List<CaseComment> toReparent = new List<CaseComment>();

  for(Case c : trigger.new)
  {       
    if(subjectToCaseList.get(c.Subject) != null)
    {
      subjectToCaseList.get(c.Subject).add(c);
    }
    else
    {
      subjectToCaseList.put(c.Subject, new List<Case> {c});
      subjectToComments.put(c.Subject, new List<CaseComment>());
    }
  }

  // this will grab all comments, even those that don't need to be reparented.
  // there's definitely room for some optimisation in this code ;)
  for(CaseComment cc : [select Id, Parent.Subject, ParentId from CaseComment
                                      where Parent.Subject in : subjectToCaseList.keySet()])
  {
    subjectToComments.get(cc.Parent.Subject).add(cc);
  }

  // this query will return new and old cases!
  for(Case existingCase : [select Id, Subject from Case where Subject in : subjectToCase.keySet()])
  {
    // old cases should receive the new comments
    if(!trigger.newMap.keySet().contains(existingCase.Id))
    {
      for(CaseComment cc : subjectToComments.get(existingCase.subject))
      {
        cc.ParentId = existingCase.id;
        toReparent.add(cc);
      }
    }

    // only new cases are in this map so close them
    for(Case newCase : subjectToCaseList.get(existingCase.Subject))
    { 
      toUpdate.add(new Case(Id = newCase.Id, Status = 'Closed'));
    }
  }

  update toUpdate;
  update toReparent;
}
```

As the comment suggests, this only matches on subject. You'd probably want to check a few other things like who the sender is, whether the old case is closed etc.. Hopefully this gives you some ideas about how to structure the code though.

I'm pretty sure the logic is right but this has not been compiled, let alone executed and tested, so there could be a few bugs (big or small).

On a side note, having variables with similar names like `caseMap`, `caseMap1`, `caseMap2` is always going to be quite confusing and could easily result in the developer making logic errors.

In this code:

```
caseMap.put(c.Subject,c1.CommentBody);                    
caseMap2.put(c.Subject,c1.id);                    
caseMap3.put(c.Subject,c1.parentId);
```

The maps would be better named `subjectToComment`, `subjectToId` and `subjectToParentId` respectively, as then you can easily tell what should go in them; which counts doubly so for anyone else trying to read/maintain the code in the future.

**Note** I wrote this code straight in the editor here, so it's likely to have a couple of syntax errors ;)

Comment: You are missing the scenario where two duplicate cases are added in a single batch of Cases. You could change `Map<String, Case> subjectToCase` to be `Map<String, List<Case>> subjectToCases` so to handle multiple cases with the same subject in the batch.

Comment: Good call! :) Will add that now!

Comment: @BarCotter,@LaceySnr :Thanks for your reply ,But my scenario is the duplicate case should get saved first and once identified it as a duplicate then it should get closed automatically ,by adding its case comments to the previous which is open case(First case).Using AFTER EVENTS and this cases are created via Email.

Comment: @nikkey Made some changes so I tihnk it's along the right lines for your use case now. If it's not, I might have to revisit tomorrow, my brain is a tad fried atm.

Comment: @Lacey Snr :I tried the code but it throws an error as :Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger Case_AfterInsert caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Case_AfterInsert: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.Case_AfterInsert: line 46, column 1

Comment: Made a quick change... should be ok now, if not you'll need to change the code where the dupes are marked to put the IDs into a set, query for those cases and then update them. Time for bed for me!

Comment: @LaceySnr:I tried making the changes in the code by adding the set<ID> CaseId = new set<ID>(); , CaseId.add(c.Id);But stil it throws and Error.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Lacey Snr :I tried the code  again,The First Case itself is getting closed before we create the Second case and while creating the second case it throws an Error as :Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data.Apex trigger Case_AfterInsert caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Case_AfterInsert: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: CaseComment.ParentId: Trigger.Case_AfterInsert: line 39, column 1.

Comment: @Lacey Snr :As per the requirement : 1) Create a case with Subject line (User ) ----First Case. 2) Create another case with Same Subject line [either by (Same user or different user )] .----Second Case . 3)Now System should automatically identify it as a " Duplicate case and close the case " (i.e second case) . 4)Now the Case Comments of the Closed case (i.e second case) should be added to the existing case ( i.e first case) which is open. Note :These Cases are Created VIA Email .

Comment: I can't do any more work on this @nikkey, hope you understand but SFSE isn't a place to get work done for you, I only did as much as I did as I thought it was the easiest way to show you some ideas. But for me to write things so a spec would be unfair on clients given that we charge for this kind of thing.